# AWS Mobile Hub - serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-mobilehub

I'm developing a mobile application using AWS Mobile Hub but this is my first time using this. I was just wondering if anyone could explain if a server also needs to be set up to provide the Mobile Hub services? I'm a little confused how it would work if these is no server dedicated to storing this information however there is no mention of needing to do this on the site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a server is not needed to develop applications using AWS Mobile Hub.
You can use AWS Lambda functions to execute your backend logic. Storing files can be done using AWS S3. Authentication can be managed using AWS Cognito.

Basically, your mobile app will use your platform's (iOS, Android, etc) SDK to interact with AWS services. Although you could setup your own backend server using EC2 instances, you are not required to. You could very well go serverless and create a RESTful API using AWS API Gateway and Lambda functions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful reply, that really helps it to make more sense! If you don't mind, I just have one more quick question: you say you can set up your own backend server using EC2 - what could be an advantage of doing this, if any? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Using EC2 instances allows you to choose your own OS (you can't control that on Lambda), you can install all sorts of packages more easily (e.g. installing ffmpeg on EC2 might be easier than trying to use it in Lambda), you can use CRON jobs, you benefit from a wider range of performance options (you can got all the way up to 384 GB RAM instances if you want, whereas Lambda limits you to 3 GB).

Comment: WRT cronjobs, you can create scheduled jobs in AWS Lambda, also.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Comment: Thank you both very much for your responses! :)